# contenteditable is not working with draggable feature

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, contenteditable, resizable

In this code `contenteditable` is not working, what mistake did I make here?
I want more than one `contenteditable` element in this div.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #element { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>


<div style="width:500px;height:500px;border:1px solid;"> 
    <div id="element" class="ui-widget-content">
      <p contenteditable='true' style="border:1px solid;">Drag me around</p>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please specify what is actually not working and what you want it to do.

Comment: Actually, with the code that you've presented, `contenteditable` works just fine.  You neglected to include the Javascript code that makes the element draggable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #element { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>


<div style="width:500px;height:500px;border:1px solid;"> 
    <div id="element" class="ui-widget-content">
      <p contenteditable='true' style="border:1px solid;">Drag me around</p>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```